# Find the folder name and mapping name details impacted by particular target table in informatica

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter, database-metadata, informatica-data-integration-hub

I need to find the informatica objects dependent on one table.

Please help me with the metadata sql query to get the folder name detail and mapping name which are impacted by this specific target table.

I am not aware of the informatica folder name. There are about 15 folders in our project and the mapping might available in any folder among those.

Basically I only have a table name which is getting loaded by informatica job which I need to find. Please help!

I tried with some queries available on internet but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT FOLDER.NAME AS FOLDER_NAME, 
                MAPPING.NAME AS MAPPING_NAME 
FROM REP_SRC_MAPPING AS MAPPING 
JOIN REP_SRC_MAPPING_TBL AS MAPPING_TBL ON MAPPING.MAPPING_ID = MAPPING_TBL.MAPPING_ID 
JOIN REP_ALL_TBL AS TARGET_TBL ON MAPPING_TBL.TBL_ID = TARGET_TBL.TBL_ID 
JOIN REP_FOLDER AS FOLDER ON MAPPING.FOLDER_ID = FOLDER.FOLDER_ID 
WHERE TARGET_TBL.TBL_NAME = '<target_table_name>';
```

Comment: It's giving error as table not exist for rep_folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).